# My platy is holding fry when will she give birth?

Tags: fish

Hi my platy gave birth to one fry 4 days ago I tried to catch the fry buy as I took my eyes off it, it disappeared presumably eaten. I caught the mother and put her in a tub as did not have a breeding box I waiting an hour or so but she had no more I think it's because I stressed her out. I can see she is still pregnant as her belly is the same and she has the gravid spot and still doing the behaviour of a pregnant fish. My question is when will she have the rest? Thank you I have also turned up the heat a bit to encourage her

Answer (score 3):

In general, moving a pregnant platy is a bad idea.  You want to have the female in an aquarium where you want the fry to be born, then remove the mother after she gives birth to prevent her eating her young.  I keep a large ball of java moss in with my platy-mommy which seems to give the fry plenty of hiding places.

Moving a pregnant platy, even to a divider, is likely to increase the stress on the fish and increase the likelihood that she terminates in order to protect herself.  You can place a male in the female's tank for breeding, but remember that platys can give birth to multiple fry with only one fertilization)

If you don't have a separate aquarium for your platy-mommy, consider adding a ball of java moss or plenty of other hiding places somehow.  I have never had a tank divider work and my fish always seem stressed inside them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, it might even regress the pregnancy.

Put her in the aquarium again and add some hiding places. I've used LEGOS before, and it worked. Even the mother as the urge to eats them..